# How to transform a square legend to point legend in sf

Tags: r

How to replace a square format legend in sf plot grafic! 
reproducible code:

```
data(meuse, package = "sp")

meuse_sf = st_as_sf(meuse, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 28992, agr = "constant")
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = meuse_sf, aes(colour = landuse))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it with `show.legend` argument.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

data(meuse, package = "sp")

meuse_sf = st_as_sf(meuse, 
                    coords = c("x", "y"), 
                    crs = 28992, 
                    agr = "constant")

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = meuse_sf, aes(colour = landuse), show.legend = "point")
```

[image]